# Get selected Datagrid row index or column index

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, row

How could I possibly get the selected row index of a DataGrid and then set it manually?

Greetings

Pethor

Comment: Are you using MVVM or just code behind?

Comment: [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0cdf2968-00e8-4ea5-aea0-ffd0e8230110) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Get selected row index:

```
int i = myDataGrid.SelectedIndex;
```

Set selected row Index:

```
myDataGrid.SelectedIndex = 4;
```